# How can I pass $scope to a service in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Below are my 2 services. When routing to a url, I resolve "OtherService.promise". But for some routes, I do not want to use the promise, instead I want to use some scope variable in AppService method. How can I achieve this?

```
app.factory("AppService", function(OtherService){ 
    var object = {};
    object.method = function() {
        return OtherService.get();
    }
    return object; 
});

app.factory("OtherService", function($http) {
    var data = null;
    var promise = $http.get('/get').success(function (response) {
       data = response
    });
    return {
       promise: promise,
       get: function(){
           return data.html;
       }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: added a method in the service and a variable in its scope. In the controller you can do `AppService.setScope($scope)` and you're good to go.

Not sure I understand what you mean, but would something like this work:

```
app.factory("AppService", function(OtherService){ 
    var scope = {};
    var object = {};
    object.method = function(mode) {
        return mode === 'promise' ? OtherService.get() : scope;
    }

    object.setScope = function(_scope) {
        scope = _scope;
    }
    return object; 
});


app.factory("OtherService", function($http) {
    var data = null;
    var promise = $http.get('/get').success(function (response) {
       data = response
    });
    return {
        promise: promise,
        get: function(){
            return data.html;
        }
 })
```

Should probably add a check to see data is valid when you `get`, just to be safe.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want. But for something else, I want to return a $scope variable. How can I get that $scope variable in OtherService

Comment: Where does the scope come from?

Comment: $scope is in my controller. I want to pass that to the Service.

Comment: @pleasedelete so you want to save a reference to that scope in the service? Edited my original answer, let me know if it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are there for you to use, to avoid nasty callback hell. What it seems you are trying to do is turn an asynchronous process into a synchronous process, which is somewhere that you do not want to go.

Embrace promises, they are EXTREMELY helpful readable, I suggest taking a look at the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

Comment: Promises are helpful. But what I want to do here is for some routes, I do not want to use "OtherService" promise, but a scope variable in AppService.

Comment: But you would have no idea of the value has been set until after the promise had been resolved